# Conexão entre 3 tabelas para resgatar informaçoes, sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo 3 tabelas com esta estrutura

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu tentei mas só consegui entrar em duas tabelas, mas precisaria que fosse nas 3 para "economizar/limpar" código.

é necessário entrar na tabela `helpcenter_topics` pegar uns `20` tópicos mais `recentemente inseridos`, pegar o `username` de quem postou levando em conta que na tabela `helpcenter_topics` a coluna `uid` representa o `idu` associativo que a liga na  tabela `users` e também pegar o `username` da última pessoa que postou uma resposta naquele tópico levanto em conta que a tabla `topics_answers` é onde se guarda as respostas e que o `topic_id` é o `id` associativo que liga a `helpcenter_topics`

como realizar isto em uma linha de código só?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Uma observação, você não está salvando o horário da resposta então não tem como saber quem foi o último.</strike> Tente isso:

```
SELECT ht.title, upost.username, 
       (SELECT ureply.username FROM topics_answers ta
        INNER JOIN users ureply on ureply.idu = ta.uid
        WHERE ta.topic_id = ht.id /* filtra somente do tópico atual */
        ORDER BY ta.id DESC /* resposta mais recente */
        LIMIT 1)
FROM helpcenter_topics ht
INNER JOIN users upost on upost.idu = ht.uid
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: @user3163662 Feito ;)